# Blocked Bounces and Resending: Should I do it?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm performing my IP-Warmup plan according to the Exact Target published domain limits.

I sent an email today and had my deliverability at 89%, with the majority of the bounces being due to 'Blocked Bounces'.

I'm trying to query the subscribers that were block-bounced and put them into a data extension in an attempt to mail them again.

Is this a bad idea?

Either way, how can I query that list into a new data extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely NOT resend to these people while just starting to warm up your IP. The beginning is a crucial part of building your IP/Domain reputation, and you should take no chances until it has been thoroughly warmed up.

A block bounce is essentially the server not trusting your email and rejecting them from delivery.  Sending to these people again will in fact worsen your reputation as the server views multiple attempts with the same email in a short period of time to be 'spammy'.

Your best bet is to (for now) cut them out and suppress them until you have a foundation for your IP reputation and can begin to take chances with reputation.

If these are subscribers you have a relationship with already (and other means of communication with), you can ask them to White list your new IP (and/or Domain) so that their mail server will skip the filtering process and you can then resend to them with no reputation issues.

See below for SFMC definition of Block Bounce: (https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/bounce_mail_management/)

**Block Bounce**

A block bounce (which is considered a type of soft bounce) occurs when the email server rejects the email due to filter issues, such as URL blocks, lack of proper authentication, or the domain or IP address is found on a blacklist utilized by the receiving domain. A subscriber who receives a block bounce will be re-tried in the next email send.

The following describes the causes of a block bounce.

- Complaint:   Your email is blocked due to complaints
- Blacklist    IP address is on a blacklist
- Content  Message was filtered due to content
- URL Block:   Emails containing your URLs are blocked
- Authentication   Message lacks required authentication

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have to send the same email to 100K current customers. I've broken it down into a two week mailing process based on the domain limits set in the documentation.

Is a week too long to wait to send the rest? Should it be a day between mailings? I sent 89K this morning, and 7.5K Block-bounced. I was within the domain mailing limits as well.

Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: Well the main variable for this is the health and activity of your list. I would recommend only sending to those that have high open/interaction rates as this will greatly help build your reputation.  There are so many nuances into deliverability and IP reputation management, there is no definite answer to your question without much more insight. In general, I would break that 100k into 20k a day Mon-Fri and remove all the bounces (except soft) prior to each send.  Sending in large numbers and erratically can also hurt. It is better to be consistent.

Comment: I'm still looking for info on how to query those Block-Bounces (and now the people who engaged (i.e: opened)). I saw a link a while back with a way to query the tracking data, but I can't seem to find it now. can you provide a link?

Thanks!

Comment: simplest would be to use measures (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/measures/) but to query bounce info, you would need to use the bounce dataview (https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_bounce/)

Comment: Does JourneyBuilder automatically remove block bounces from additional sending?

Comment: I believe JB follows the same protocol as your default settings in SFMC - which requires a certain number of bounces within a certain amount of time before they will be labeled as bounced or held in all subscribers. Until then they will continue to send.